# lumia 535 won't share network

Tags: nokia-lumia-535, internet-sharing

My Lumia 535 suddenly stopped allowing other devices to connect to its hotspot....keep getting unable to join network whenever my other devices try to connect...most times they cant even detect the WiFi signal from my Lumia and when they do,they wont connect. At one point I edited the APN to manual and set network mode to ipv4 only worked for few minutes then stopped...I have also tried both soft and hard reset...nothing worked...please is there a solution?..and how do I go about getting it

Comment: This is a common bug in windows 10 mobile, by the way are you on 10?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue even in windows 10 , can't say about the new anniversary update. There is only one way to keep the hotspot running , that is never let your phone go to sleep the screen must be always on and the hotspot setting must be opened. Don't use any other apps .

yes yes i know this is stupid but this is the only way.

and if the phone goes to sleep you must switch off both cellular and wifi then reenable them for the hotspot to work properly.

I hope this helped.